# JavaScript send value to another function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send value of "MyProject" Onther function as bellow. (Simply I want to send value from SPservice to another Script) . How can I combined this?

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "MyCustomList",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var MyProject = $(this).attr("ows_Project");
  
  });
    }
  });
});
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {  
            var appointments = new Array();
            var appointment1 = {
                
                description: "George brings projector for presentations.",
                location: "",
                subject: "Quarterly Project Review Meeting",
                Project: <I want MyProject to here>,
    
                
            }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Combine it how? You will either need to call a function using that as a parameter, return that value to something, or set a variable to the value that can be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name the first function and at the end

```
return MyProject;
```

and then on the second function, you just call the previous function doing

```
Project: NameOfFirstFunction(),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "MyCustomList",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
           $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var MyProject = $(this).attr("ows_Project");
                myFunction(MyProject)
           });
        }
    });
   });

function myFunction(myProject){
        var appointments = new Array();
        var appointment1 = {

            description: "George brings projector for presentations.",
            location: "",
            subject: "Quarterly Project Review Meeting",
            Project: myProject,


        }
}
</script>
```